# Use cases for Java concurrent utilities

Tags: java, concurrency, summary

I have read Java Concurrency in Practice and this is a great reference, but I would like to see a concise single page summary of the use cases of the java.util.concurrent package.

For instance:

- Why use a concurrent collection over a synchronized collection?
- When should the atomic classes be preferred over explicit locking?
- When should Locks be used over synchronization?
- What are the alternatives to wait() and notify(), notifyAll()?
- When should a CompletionService be used?

What are the pros/cons and pitfalls to be aware of?

Comment: This sounds like homework questions.

Comment: Not really :) Just a quick reference to choose the correct tool for the job.

Comment: So you read the book and still have these questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Why use a concurrent collection over a synchronized collection?

Because a `synchronized` collection only protects data from corruption due to concurrent access. This does not mean that the `synchronized` collections are *optimized* for concurrent access. Far from it, in fact - a `ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent` is a much better mechanism for a `compareAndSet` than locking the entire `Map` for reads.

- When should the atomic classes be preferred over explicit locking?

The `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong` classes should always be used (in my opinion) over locking by hand with a primitive because they are more concise. Consider:

```
synchronized (lock) { 
    int old = counter;
    counter++;
    return old;
}
```

When compared with:

```
int old = counter.getAndIncrement();
```

I have to say though, that the classes suffer from their lack of *waitability*. For example, you often want some synchronized boolean where you `wait` on the boolean condition. These were available as `WaitableBoolean` in the old Doug Lea concurrency library but they were jettisoned in `j.u.c`, I'm not sure why.

- When should Locks be used over synchronization?

This is a more complicated question because usage of `Locks` carries some overhead. In fact, it's often said that there's no pint in using a `ReadWriteLock` in *typical* cases. One scenario *where locks must be used* is where the locking of a resource and its unlocking *cannot be done in the same lexical scope*. `synchronized` is powerless to help in cases such as these.

- What are the alternatives to wait() and notify(), notifyAll()?

`await`, `signal` and `signalAll`

- When should a CompletionService be used?

A completion service is useful in the case where the consumption of a result of a computation does not need to be accessed at the point the computation was submitted but where *it is important* that the completion of the computation (or its result, or success) be known by your program. This might be, for example, to monitor the proportion of failed tasks (which threw exceptions), or it may be for resource cleanup.

Comment: One use case for Locks is when you want different implementations for different clients.  Eg, a multi-threaded client can use a standard lock, a single-threaded a noop lock, and in load tests for race condition detection you might want to use a lock that aborts on concurrent access.

Answer (score 2):

```
What are the alternatives to wait() and notify(), notifyAll()
```

One very good alternative to *wait(), notify()* and *notifyAll()* is to **NOT USE THEM AT ALL**.

200KLOC codebase here that is *heavily* multithreaded. We're spreading the load on countless cores and have armies of producers/consumers scheme etc.

Instances of *wait(), notify()* or *notifyAll()* in our code?

Zero.

I re-put the emphasis on the fact that it is an heavily multi-threaded application: *latches, poison pills, java.util.concurrent.** and whatnots *everywhere*. But *wait(), notify()* or *notifyAll()*: zero instances.

This is *really* low-level stuff that should only have its uses in concurrency utilities/frameworks.

From Joshua Bloch, in *"Effective Java"*, at the very beginning of the *"Threads"* chapter:

**"If there is a library that can save you from doing low-level multi-threaded programming, by all means use it."**